# Doing a custom legend of marker sizes in matplotlib using a lambda function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am playing with the third example of "[Scatter plots with a legend](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html)" in the matplotlib manual.

[image]

I have tweaked the marker sizes to:

```
s = (50 / price) ** 2
```

And as an input to [legend_elements](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.legend_elements) I am using:

```
func=lambda s: 50 / np.sqrt(s)
```

I get the output below. The marker sizes of the legend are wrong. Why is that?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


volume = np.random.rayleigh(27, size=40)
amount = np.random.poisson(10, size=40)
ranking = np.random.normal(size=40)
price = np.random.uniform(1, 10, size=40)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

s = (50 / price) ** 2

scatter = ax.scatter(volume, amount, c=ranking, s=s,
                     vmin=-3, vmax=3, cmap="Spectral", label=price)

legend1 = ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(num=5),
                    loc="upper left", title="Ranking")
ax.add_artist(legend1)

kw = dict(prop="sizes", num=5, color=scatter.cmap(0.7), fmt="$ {x:.2f}",
          func=lambda s: 50 / np.sqrt(s),
          )
legend2 = ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(**kw),
                    loc="lower right", title="Price")

for p, v, a in zip(price, volume, amount):
    ax.annotate(round(p, 0), (v, a))
plt.show()
```

Comment: @importanceofbeingernest Did you write the function `legend_elements` of matplotlib? Could you help me with my question above?

Comment: Notifications will only work if the user already interacted with the question in some sort. Hence I only saw this comment through the linked pull request. If people need to contact me, they might find my email through the matplotlib project - else, notifications on [discourse.matplotlib.org](https://discourse.matplotlib.org) would also directly reach me.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks! I didn't know that. Very helpful to know going forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be related to the inverse relationship between price and marker size. The way the data is calculated in `legend_elements` doesn't account for this, and the calculation doesn't quite work. I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/17546).

The problem is in `np.interp` that expects increasing input for the second argument. Here is a work around for now that sorts the input first:

```
legend2 = ax.legend(*legend_elements(scatter, **kw),
                loc="lower right", title="Price")
```

Run this after defining `legend_elements` as:

```
def legend_elements(self, prop="colors", num="auto",
                 fmt=None, func=lambda x: x, **kwargs):
    """
    Creates legend handles and labels for a PathCollection. This is useful
    for obtaining a legend for a :meth:`~.Axes.scatter` plot. E.g.::

        scatter = plt.scatter([1, 2, 3],  [4, 5, 6],  c=[7, 2, 3])
        plt.legend(*scatter.legend_elements())

    Also see the :ref:`automatedlegendcreation` example.

    Parameters
    ----------
    prop : string, optional, default *"colors"*
        Can be *"colors"* or *"sizes"*. In case of *"colors"*, the legend
        handles will show the different colors of the collection. In case
        of "sizes", the legend will show the different sizes.
    num : int, None, "auto" (default), array-like, or `~.ticker.Locator`,
        optional
        Target number of elements to create.
        If None, use all unique elements of the mappable array. If an
        integer, target to use *num* elements in the normed range.
        If *"auto"*, try to determine which option better suits the nature
        of the data.
        The number of created elements may slightly deviate from *num* due
        to a `~.ticker.Locator` being used to find useful locations.
        If a list or array, use exactly those elements for the legend.
        Finally, a `~.ticker.Locator` can be provided.
    fmt : str, `~matplotlib.ticker.Formatter`, or None (default)
        The format or formatter to use for the labels. If a string must be
        a valid input for a `~.StrMethodFormatter`. If None (the default),
        use a `~.ScalarFormatter`.
    func : function, default *lambda x: x*
        Function to calculate the labels. Often the size (or color)
        argument to :meth:`~.Axes.scatter` will have been pre-processed
        by the user using a function *s = f(x)* to make the markers
        visible; e.g. *size = np.log10(x)*. Providing the inverse of this
        function here allows that pre-processing to be inverted, so that
        the legend labels have the correct values;
        e.g. *func = np.exp(x, 10)*.
    kwargs : further parameters
        Allowed keyword arguments are *color* and *size*. E.g. it may be
        useful to set the color of the markers if *prop="sizes"* is used;
        similarly to set the size of the markers if *prop="colors"* is
        used. Any further parameters are passed onto the `.Line2D`
        instance. This may be useful to e.g. specify a different
        *markeredgecolor* or *alpha* for the legend handles.

    Returns
    -------
    tuple (handles, labels)
        with *handles* being a list of `.Line2D`  objects
        and *labels* a matching list of strings.
    """
    handles = []
    labels = []
    hasarray = self.get_array() is not None
    if fmt is None:
        fmt = mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False, useMathText=True)
    elif isinstance(fmt, str):
        fmt = mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter(fmt)
    fmt.create_dummy_axis()

    if prop == "colors":
        if not hasarray:
            warnings.warn("Collection without array used. Make sure to "
                          "specify the values to be colormapped via the "
                          "`c` argument.")
            return handles, labels
        u = np.unique(self.get_array())
        size = kwargs.pop("size", mpl.rcParams["lines.markersize"])
    elif prop == "sizes":
        u = np.unique(self.get_sizes())
        color = kwargs.pop("color", "k")
    else:
        raise ValueError("Valid values for `prop` are 'colors' or "
                         f"'sizes'. You supplied '{prop}' instead.")

    fmt.set_bounds(func(u).min(), func(u).max())
    if num == "auto":
        num = 9
        if len(u) <= num:
            num = None
    if num is None:
        values = u
        label_values = func(values)
    else:
        if prop == "colors":
            arr = self.get_array()
        elif prop == "sizes":
            arr = self.get_sizes()
        if isinstance(num, mpl.ticker.Locator):
            loc = num
        elif np.iterable(num):
            loc = mpl.ticker.FixedLocator(num)
        else:
            num = int(num)
            loc = mpl.ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=num, min_n_ticks=num-1,
                                         steps=[1, 2, 2.5, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10])
        label_values = loc.tick_values(func(arr).min(), func(arr).max())
        cond = ((label_values >= func(arr).min()) &
                (label_values <= func(arr).max()))
        label_values = label_values[cond]
        yarr = np.linspace(arr.min(), arr.max(), 256)
        xarr = func(yarr)
        ix = np.argsort(xarr)
        values = np.interp(label_values, xarr[ix], yarr[ix])

    kw = dict(markeredgewidth=self.get_linewidths()[0],
              alpha=self.get_alpha())
    kw.update(kwargs)

    for val, lab in zip(values, label_values):
        if prop == "colors":
            color = self.cmap(self.norm(val))
        elif prop == "sizes":
            size = np.sqrt(val)
            if np.isclose(size, 0.0):
                continue
        h = mlines.Line2D([0], [0], ls="", color=color, ms=size,
                          marker=self.get_paths()[0], **kw)
        handles.append(h)
        if hasattr(fmt, "set_locs"):
            fmt.set_locs(label_values)
        l = fmt(lab)
        labels.append(l)

    return handles, labels
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Not quite. Because as you can see the prices range from 1 to 10: `price = np.random.uniform(1, 10, size=40)`

Comment: Actually, your original calculation should be correct now that I take a second look. I'm actually not sure what the issue is... I'll take a further look to see if I can't spot something.

Comment: Updated answer. Appears to be a bug.

Comment: Ahhhh, it was a bug. Thanks! You might want to explain to others what your changes were. I ran a diff and it's clear to me: ```<             xarr = np.linspace(arr.min(), arr.max(), 256)
<             values = np.interp(label_values, func(xarr), xarr)
---
>             yarr = np.linspace(arr.min(), arr.max(), 256)
>             xarr = func(yarr)
>             ix = np.argsort(xarr)
>             values = np.interp(label_values, xarr[ix], yarr[ix])```

Answer (score 1):

You can also manually create your own legend. The trick here is that you have to apply `np.sqrt` to sizes in the legend for some reason I don't quite follow but @busybear has in her snippet.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


volume = np.random.rayleigh(27, size=40)
amount = np.random.poisson(10, size=40)
ranking = np.random.normal(size=40)
price = np.random.uniform(1, 10, size=40)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

s = (50 / price) ** 2

scatter = ax.scatter(volume, amount, c=ranking, s=s,
                     vmin=-3, vmax=3, cmap="Spectral", label=price)

legend1 = ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(num=5),
                    loc="upper left", title="Ranking")
ax.add_artist(legend1)

# # easy legend

# kw = dict(prop="sizes", num=5, color=scatter.cmap(0.7), fmt="$ {x:.2f}",
#           func=lambda s: 50 / np.sqrt(s),
#           )
# legend2 = ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(**kw),
#                     loc="lower right", title="Price")
# ax.add_artist(legend2)

# manual legend

legend_values = np.array([2,4,6,8])
legend_sizes = (50 / legend_values) ** 2

# IMPORTANT: for some reason the square root needs to be applied to sizes in the legend
legend_sizes_sqrt = np.sqrt(legend_sizes)

elements3 = [Line2D([0], [0], color=scatter.cmap(0.7), lw=0, marker="o", linestyle=None, markersize=s) for s in legend_sizes_sqrt]
legend3 = ax.legend(elements3, [f"$ {p:.2f}" for p in legend_values], loc='lower right', title="Price")
ax.add_artist(legend3)

for p, v, a in zip(price, volume, amount):
    ax.annotate(round(p, 0), (v, a))
plt.show()
```

[image]